# as is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql, sql

i am getting issue at return @averagesalary1 and from the line as ,error being not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

```
create function world.function1()
returns  double 
as
begin 
    DECLARE averagesalary1 double;
    select @averagesalary1=avg(averagesalary) from coampanies;
    return @averagesalary1
end;
```

what seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Where did you get AS from it's not in the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html , perhaps from another sql dialect? Also in mysql you may need to set delimiters https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server supports the `AS` keyword in `CREATE FUNCTION` syntax as you show. This is different from MySQL syntax.

You must keep in mind that what you learned in one implementation may be different in another, so you have read the documentation for the brand of SQL database you use, and don't assume that they are compatible.

Another difference between Microsoft and MySQL that is shown in your code example is that a declared variable and a variable with the `@` symbol are in fact different variables. A value in one is not the same value in the other.

Here's how I would write your function in MySQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION world.function1()
RETURNS DOUBLE 
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN 
    DECLARE averagesalary1 double;
    SELECT AVG(averagesalary) FROM coampanies INTO averagesalary1;
    RETURN averagesalary1;
END;
```